# MYSQL-JOIN Query return empty result

Tags: mysql

**hobby_users Table:**

[image]

**subcategory_master Table:**

[image]

**My Query:**

```
SELECT hobby_users.user_subcategory_id,GROUP_CONCAT(subcategory_master.subcategory_name) AS subcategory_name
        FROM `hobby_users` 
        INNER JOIN subcategory_master
        WHERE hobby_users.hobby_users_id='1' AND subcategory_master.subcategory_master_id IN(SELECT user_subcategory_id FROM `hobby_users` WHERE hobby_users_id='1')
```

**Actual Result:**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

**Note:** The sub-query retuns `1,2`

Please suggest or help for where I am wrong.

Comment: If it's not too late, you should seriously reconsider your schema, specifically the `user_subcategory_id` column. If it is too late, have a look at [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For group_concat you should use GROUP BY for grouping

```
SELECT 
   hobby_users.user_subcategory_id
  ,GROUP_CONCAT(subcategory_master.subcategory_name) AS subcategory_name
FROM `hobby_users` 
INNER JOIN subcategory_master
WHERE hobby_users.hobby_users_id='1' 
  AND subcategory_master.subcategory_master_id IN (SELECT user_subcategory_id FROM `hobby_users` WHERE hobby_users_id='1')
GROUP BY hobby_users.user_subcategory_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
drop table if exists hobby_users;
create table hobby_users(hobby_users_id int, user_name varchar(3), user_subcategory_id varchar(3));

drop table if exists subcategory_master;
create table subcategory_master(subcategory_master_id int, subcategory_name varchar(3));

insert into hobby_users values
(1,'abc','1,2'),
(2,'def','1,3');

insert into subcategory_master values
(1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb'),(3,'ccc'),(4,'ddd');
*/


MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT h.hobby_users_id,
    ->    h.user_subcategory_id
    ->   ,GROUP_CONCAT(sm.subcategory_name) AS subcategory_name
    -> FROM `hobby_users` h
    -> INNER JOIN subcategory_master sm
    -> WHERE h.hobby_users_id='1'
    ->   AND
    ->   find_in_set(sm.subcategory_master_id,h.user_subcategory_id) > 0
    -> GROUP BY h.user_subcategory_id;
+----------------+---------------------+------------------+
| hobby_users_id | user_subcategory_id | subcategory_name |
+----------------+---------------------+------------------+
|              1 | 1,2                 | aaa,bbb          |
+----------------+---------------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'hobby_users.hobby_users_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Substitute the table name with the alias name (h)

Comment: It will return `subcategory_name` as `null`

Comment: Not with the information you provided. I have edited the the solution to include the hobby_users_id test and the result when the code is run.